# Google Chrome Blocks AWS Amazon S3 Downloads. How To Fix?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-chrome, amazon-s3

I uploaded an excel file in a zip file and made it PUBLIC in Amazon AWS S3.
But when I click Download I get the message that the file is not commonly downloaded and may be dangerous. Is there a fix for this?
I intend to let other people download it so the message is bad you might say.

Comment: Blocking downloads from S3 would render Chrome pretty useless, so you have almost certainly overgeneralized the nature or scope of the problem in your question.  Check your bucket's URL at https://www.google.com/transparencyreport/safebrowsing/diagnostic/.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I found out that Chrome blocks certains files. There was another dude who had the same issue with EXE files, noted they are more risky but they were good. In his case they were blocked UNTIL Google crawled his site. My files BECAME downloadable one hour or two AFTER I posted them on Amazon. Nothing new tweaked. Just waited. FYI. Thanks again